# Infinite Loop while using Do while in SAS

Tags: sas

I am very new but keen to learn SAS coding.I have 2  data sets a and b namely dt1 and dt2 which consist of columns  a for dt1 and b and c for dt2:

```
a      b      c
2014   2008   2
       2009   3
       2014   4 
       2015   5
```

I am trying to get the nth row of the c column when the element which is at nth row of b column is equal to a(1)
Here it is c=4;
I wrote a code below.

```
DATA dt1;
   set dt1;
data dt2;
   set dt2;
   i=1;
   do while (b ne a);
      i=i+1;
   end;
   call symput('ROW_NUMBER',i);
run;

proc print data = dt2(keep = c obs = &ROW_NUMBER firstobs = &ROW_NUMBER);
run;
```

but this code enters in an infinite loop and I could not find any solution for this. I appreciate if you help solve this issue. 
Thanks

Comment: @Bendy I don't think the edit reflects the question. OP says they are beginning with two data sets, `dt1` with column `a` (one row), and `dt2` with columns `b` and `c`.

Comment: yes absolutely you are right @DWAL

Comment: Ah I did wonder - thanks @Dwal...and thanks for correcting Joe

Answer (score 2):

I think you should learn the basic syntax of the data step before trying to use macro variables. A lot of what you're doing makes little sense. Here is an explanation of [how the data step works](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001290590.htm). You will do yourself a huge favor if you study that.

Here's how to do an inner join in `proc sql`, which seems to be more in line with your goal here. This simply selects the values of c where dt1.a is equal to dt2.b:

```
proc sql;
select c
from dt1 inner join dt2 on dt1.a = dt2.b;
quit;
```

If you were to use a data step, you'd do something like this the following.

```
data out(keep=c);
  set dt1;
  do until (a=b or eof);
    set dt2 end=eof;
    if a=b then output;
  end;
run;
proc print data=out noobs;
run;
```

Use the `end=` option to create temporary variable `eof` which allows you to end the loop after the last row of dt2 is read.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, it really worked and  I will read the  documentation on how data step works!

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple MERGE.  You just need to rename the variables to match.  This assumes they're both sorted by the value (a/b).  You can then set the macro variable in that data step or do whatever you want.

```
data want;
  merge dt1(in=_a rename=a=b) dt2(in=_b);
  by b;
  if _a and _b;
  call symput("ROW_NUMBER",c);
run;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help joe but it gives this error:ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set dt2.

Comment: See the second sentence - "This assumes they're both sorted by the value (a/b)."  Use `PROC SORT` to sort your data sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define macro variables:

```
data _null_;
set dt2;
if _n_=1 then set dt1;
if a=b then do;
call symput('c_val',c); 
call symput('row_num',_n_);
end;
run;

%put &row_num &c_val;
```